# Exchange 2007 Standard - database size limit reached - what can I do?

Tags: database, exchange-2007

My understanding is that the 250GB limit in SP1 is just a soft limit, correct?

If I follow this article:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb232092.aspx

and set the database to 260GB will that work to give me a little bit of time to work with Microsoft on this?

I don't really have any free space left on this logical drive (about 12GB).

I also heard that I could move the catalogdata folder (indexing folder?) off this drive to help alleviate space as well, which in turn would allow me to bump that registry key to 270GB.

Another alternative might be to create an additional mailbox database for this Storage Group on a separate logical drive and move some users into it, but I want to be certain this will actually help with space on the first .edb file as well before going this route.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is only a hard limit of 16TB with EDBs in 2007, though, and they're perfectly fine up until then. Once you modify the registry entry, you should be fine.

If you're dead-set on getting off the database you're currently using, then you have two options.

It is possible to shrink a database, but it must be offline and it can take a while.

You could also just create two additional databases, then migrate your mailboxes off in a somewhat balanced manner to both. After, you can just delete the old bloated one.

Comment: Is the dword in decimal 260 (to make it 260GB)?  and do I need to restart the information store at that point?

Comment: Also, if I create an additional database and use the "Move Mailbox" can I do that realtime without user downtime?  I know it won't actually remove the physical space, but it would free up white space, correct?

Comment: Moving the mailbox is indeed in realtime. The size limit is decimal as far as I can tell. Changing the limit will require a restart of the information store.

Comment: After you move the boxes, you'd then want to defragment the store. I believe that would require free space equivalent to the size of the store, though.

Comment: @Bigbio2002 It's possible to defrag the store while using another drive for temp space. Check the Eseutil switches.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I upped the limit in the registry.  Still critically low on disk space though, so I'm going to look at adding an external SCSI enclosure with enough disk to comfortably move the database to.

Comment: @TheCleaner Good to hear it! If you're looking to just move the database wholesale, things get a lot easier. You don't have to create another, you can just change the location. If you need help with it, feel free to open another question.